# REST API - TranslatePress plugin for Wordpress 403 error

Tags: wordpress, translate

I am trying to make a website multilanguage. And therefore I installed the plugin: translate press. (https://translatepress.com). However, when I try to receive all the products in a certain language (de) it does not seem to work and gives me a 403 error. Calling the follow URL:

https://websitename.com/de/wp-json/wc/v3/products/

> ```
> "message": "The iss do not match with this server.",
> ```

I am using the JWT auth plugin as well.

Has anyone had some experience with this tool?